# Cannot Delete The Specified Item

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to get and item(Ticket) from List and delete based on the invoice number. but it deletes the first item in list.

```
private void btnTktDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uOp = true;
        if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Ticket tkt = (Ticket)MainListBox.SelectedItem;    

            List<Ticket> tlist = GetList<Ticket>(tklp);
            Ticket TheTicket = tlist.Find(x => x.InvoiceNumber == tkt.InvoiceNumber);
            List<Transaction> tranlist = GetList<Transaction>(trlp);


            if (TheTicket != null)
            {
                Int32 number = TheTicket.InvoiceNumber;
                tlist.RemoveAll(x=>x.InvoiceNumber == number);
                tranlist.RemoveAll(x => x.InvoiceNumber == number);
                SaveList(trlp, tranlist);
                SaveList(tklp, tlist);
            }

         //   MainListBox.DataSource = null;
         //   MainListBox.DataSource = GetList<Ticket>(tklp);
         //   dgvExport.DataSource = null;
         //   dgvExport.DataSource = GetList<Ticket>(tklp);

            uOp = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Only you can debug this, put the breakpoint and monitor the data in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code suggests multiple tickets can have the same invoice number. this doesn't feel intuitive to me - should be unique. the easiest way to get the list is to store a reference to it in a field.

```
List<Ticket> allTickets = ...

private void btnTktDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ticket ticketToRemove = (Ticket)MainListBox.SelectedItem; // need cast?
    allTickets.Remove(ticketToRemove);
    // save...
}
```